# How to get row data when clicking button which is inside a row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am creating a shopping cart with same Addtocart button on each row. as shown in the below table

[image]

I used a for loop to print each row. I want to access the data of a row in which the button is clicked. How can i do it?

Comment: Show the generated HTML code plz

Comment: You can add `data-*` attributes to each button and access them on the onclick of those buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your respoonse @nice_dev So the rows are created inside a for loop if i put data-id = "123" all the rows buttons have same data-id = "123" attribute. or is there any other way?

Comment: The value inside will be different for each row

Answer (score 1):

As @nice_dev said, you could add a custom data attribute to the buttons and access it onclick or even just traverse the html using the this keyword:

```js
function myFunction1(data){
  console.log(data)
 }
 
function myFunction2(element){
  console.log(element.parentElement.children[0].innerText)
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML traversal inline-->
<div>
  <p>Galaxy Note S7</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction1(this.parentElement.children[0].innerText)">Buy</button>
</div>
<!-- HTML traversal in JS Function-->
<div>
  <p>Galaxy Note S8</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(this)">Buy</button>
</div>
<!-- Data Tag (attribute could be retieved from JS also)-->
<div>
  <p>Galaxy Note S9</p>  
  <button data-device="Galaxy Note S9" onclick="myFunction1(this.getAttribute('data-device'))">Buy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is an API for `data-` attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset